# Amazon EC2 instance installed apache as root, not ec2-user

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, root

I am new to EC2. I have created an instance with Amazon Linux AMI x86_64 EBS and installed an Apache web server.

Now issue is that everything seems to have installed under root and I can't edit any config files as ec2-user (e.g. /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have only used Ubuntu images on EC2, not the Amazon-supplied ones, but I think this is probably fairly standard. Use sudo for each command (or sudo -s to get a shell as root, if you need to do a whole bunch of things as root).